# How to save sh script command in log file?

Tags: bash, logging, sh, history

My command is: `bash test.sh`

How to save the command context 'bash test.sh' to logfile using the command with test.sh?

Motivation: When I use the test.sh with very long argument parsing (e.g., bash test.sh --a --b --c --d .... --s) and I have to rerun the command with different argument parsing. Therefore, I want to automatically save these commands with argument parsing.

Note that `echo bash test.sh --a --b ... >log.txt && bash test.sh --a --b ...` can do as well. However, I don't want to type in such long command every time I rerun the test.sh. So I ask for help if there is any simple way to fix the problem.

I have tried to modify test.sh as the following, and running `bash test.sh --a --b ...` can not save the context `bash test.sh --a --b ...` to log.txt.

```
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
history 10 > ./log.txt
functional commands...
```

Comment: Save in what context?  You could just do `echo bash test.sh >log.txt`.  It will appear in your history as well.

Comment: Did you see `~/.bash_history`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have reedited the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. `echo "!bash" > your_file` which would fetch last cammand with `bash` and write it to file, you might want `>>` instead of single `>`
2. if the ~/.bash_history cannot be used (what would be odd, but possible) then you might write it to out file right before invoking specific command `echo bash test.sh >> your_file && bash test.sh`

Comment: Thanks! I rewrite the question to make it clear. Is there any simple way to do it within the test.sh?